# Changing IP of DNS Server machine

Tags: networking, dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am in windows server 2012R2 machine environment and there I am having my Active Directory and DNS server(local LAN) configured.

Now due to some requirement  I want to change IP of this machine and want to give it dynamic IP and this machine IP would be used for other machine connected.

My Question is that what configuration do I need to set now to use the DNS server and Active Directory

As Now the users that I maintained in my Active Directory are now no not able to connect to the server machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you have DHCP on your network, set the new DNS IP as the DNS advertised by the DHCP. If you don't have DHCP, you're good for applying that setting manually on every of your computers.

You can't use GPOs because computers need to find the DNS *before* they can use AD and download their GPOs.

Generally, *never **ever*** apply dynamic IP on DNS or DC server unsless static IP threaten your life.

Comment: I am not using DHCP and as you said I need to change setting manually on every computer. HOW? but I think since I changed the IP there should be something in DNS server that I must do ?

Comment: DNS installed on domain controllers automatically update their A and AAAA records for domain computers, so you don't have anything to do on the DNS itself. If you don't use DHCP go to TCP/IPv4 (or v6) settings on the computer's network card to set up the computer's IP and DNS.

Comment: Control Pannel -> Network & sharing center -> Local network connection -> Properties